# fpdf not working properly on new page

Tags: php, fpdf

> When I run this program, After showing Page1 properly, it would create one single page for every cell for row6's result creating 5 additional pages when there should be only 2 pages. It would create 5 Pages for 5 cells.

```
class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Page header
function Header()
{
    // Logo
    $this->Image('logo.png',10,10,30);
    // Arial bold 15
    $this->SetFont('Times','B',15);
    // Move to the right
    $this->Cell(30,30);
    // Title
    $this->Cell(0,10,'Austin Grammar School',0,1,'L');
    $this->SetFont('Arial','i',10);
    $this->Cell(90,0,'136 - E, Austin.',0,1,'R');
    $this->SetFont('Arial','U',10);
    $this->Cell(0,20,'Academic Report',0,1,'C');
    $this->SetFont('Arial',null,10);
    $this->Cell(0,-10,'First Term : 2014-2015',0, 1 ,'C');
    $this->Rect(10,40,190,10);
    $this->SetFont('Arial',null,10);
    //Student Name
    $this->SetFont('Times','',12);
    $this->Cell(0,25,'Student Name :',0, 0,'L');
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
    $this->Cell(-120,25,'Mr. Abc (2014-353-10)',0, 0,'R');
    $this->Ln(5);
    //Address
    $this->SetFont('Times',null,10);
    $this->Cell(0,25,'Address :',0, 0,'L');
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
    $this->Cell(-120,25,'174-XX PA',0, 0,'R'); 
    //DoB
    $this->SetFont('Arial',null,10);
    $this->Cell(88,15,'DOB :',0, 0,'R');
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
    $this->Cell(0,15,'20-Oct-1986',0, 0,'L');
    $this->ln(5);
    //Grade
    $this->SetFont('Arial',null,10);
    $this->Cell(160,15,'Grade :',0, 0,'R');
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
    $this->Cell(0,15,'X',0, 0,'L');
    //section
    $this->SetFont('Arial',null,10);
    $this->Cell(-10,15,'Section :',0, 0,'R');
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
    $this->Cell(0,15,'X-ZA',0, 0,'L');
    // Line break

    // Grading Table
    $this->SetXY(145,10);
    $this->SetFont('Times','B',8);
    $this->Cell(55,3,"Grading Scheme",1,1,'C');
    $this->SetFont('Times',null,7);
    $this->SetXY(145,13);
    $this->Cell(10,3,"A+",'LRB',1,'C');
    $this->SetXY(145,16);
    $this->Cell(10,3,"A",'LRB',1,'C');
    $this->SetXY(145,19);
    $this->Cell(10,3,"B",'LRB',1,'C');
    $this->SetXY(145,22);
    $this->Cell(10,3,"C",'LRB',1,'C');
    $this->SetXY(145,25);
    $this->Cell(10,3,"D",'LRB',1,'C');
    $this->SetXY(145,28);
    $this->Cell(10,3,"U",'LRB',1,'C');

    $this->SetXY(155,13);
    $this->Cell(15,3,"Humanities",'RB',1,'C');
    $this->SetXY(155,16);
    $this->Cell(15,3,"85-100",'RB',1,'C');
    $this->SetXY(155,19);
    $this->Cell(15,3,"80-84",'RB',1,'C');
    $this->SetXY(155,22);
    $this->Cell(15,3,"70-79",'RB',1,'C');
    $this->SetXY(155,25);
    $this->Cell(15,3,"60-69",'RB',1,'C');
    $this->SetXY(155,28);
    $this->Cell(15,3,"0-60",'RB',1,'C');

    $this->SetXY(170,13);
    $this->Cell(15,3,"Sciences",'RB',1,'C');
    $this->SetXY(170,16);
    $this->Cell(15,3,"85-100",'RB',1,'C');
    $this->SetXY(170,19);
    $this->Cell(15,3,"80-84",'RB',1,'C');
    $this->SetXY(170,22);
    $this->Cell(15,3,"70-79",'RB',1,'C');
    $this->SetXY(170,25);
    $this->Cell(15,3,"60-69",'RB',1,'C');
    $this->SetXY(170,28);
    $this->Cell(15,3,"0-60",'RB',1,'C');


    $this->SetXY(185,13);
    $this->Cell(15,3,"Sciences",'RB',1,'C');
    $this->SetXY(185,16);
    $this->Cell(15,3,"85-100",'RB',1,'C');
    $this->SetXY(185,19);
    $this->Cell(15,3,"80-84",'RB',1,'C');
    $this->SetXY(185,22);
    $this->Cell(15,3,"70-79",'RB',1,'C');
    $this->SetXY(185,25);
    $this->Cell(15,3,"60-69",'RB',1,'C');
    $this->SetXY(185,28);
    $this->Cell(15,3,"0-60",'RB',1,'C');
    $this->Ln(24);
    //Full Page Blue Border
    $this->SetLineWidth(1);
    $this->SetDrawColor(0,0,135);
    $this->Rect(5,5,200,285);
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
}


}

$pdf = new PDF();
$header=array('Subject','October Test ','December Exam','Remarks');
//Data loading
$pdf->AliasNbPages();

$pdf->AddPage();
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Table Header ~~~~~~~~~~
$pdf->Cell(40,20,'Subject','LT',0,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(75,10,'First Term',1,1,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'','LRB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
$pdf->Cell(25,10,'October Test','TB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(25,10,'December Exam',1,0,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(25,10,'Term Average',1,0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(125,55);
$pdf->Cell(75,20,'Teacher\'s Evaluation','TRB',0,'C',0);
//----- table Content-----

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->SetXY(10,75);
$pdf->Cell(40,40,'Biology','LRB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(50,75);
$pdf->Cell(25,40,'77','RB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(75,75);
$pdf->Cell(25,40,'87','RB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(100,75);
$pdf->Cell(25,40,'82','RB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(125,75);
$pdf->MultiCell(75,10,'dg,lfnmdonjfgdnolfdsfsgnonwedwdfwf wrfw wrfwfw wfwf wfwfwfw fwfwfwfw wwoblfnmdonjfgdnolfdsfsgnonwedwdfwf wrfw wrfwfw wfwf wfwfwfw fwfwfwfw wwob','TRB','L');
//----- Row 2-----

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->SetXY(10,115);
$pdf->Cell(40,40,'Geography','LRB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(50,115);
$pdf->Cell(25,40,'77','RB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(75,115);
$pdf->Cell(25,40,'87','RB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(100,115);
$pdf->Cell(25,40,'82','RB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(125,115);
$pdf->MultiCell(75,10,'dg,lfnmdonjfgdnolfdsfsgnonwedwdfwf wrfw wrfwfw wfwf wfwfwfw fwfwfwfw wwoblfnmdonjfgdnolfdsfsgnonwedwdfwf wrfw wrfwfw wfwf wfwfwfw fwfwfwfw wwob','TRB','L');

//----- Row 3-----

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->SetXY(10,155);
$pdf->Cell(40,40,'Food & Nutrition','LRB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(50,155);
$pdf->Cell(25,40,'77','RB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(75,155);
$pdf->Cell(25,40,'87','RB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(100,155);
$pdf->Cell(25,40,'82','RB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(125,155);
$pdf->MultiCell(75,10,'dg,lfnmdonjfgdnolfdsfsgnonwedwdfwf wrfw wrfwfw wfwf wfwfwfw fwfwfwfw wwoblfnmdonjfgdnolfdsfsgnonwedwdfwf wrfw wrfwfw wfwf wfwfwfw fwfwfwfw wwob','TRB','L');


//----- Row 4 -----

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->SetXY(10,195);
$pdf->Cell(40,40,'Economics','LRB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(50,195);
$pdf->Cell(25,40,'77','RB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(75,195);
$pdf->Cell(25,40,'87','RB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(100,195);
$pdf->Cell(25,40,'82','RB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(125,195);
$pdf->MultiCell(75,10,'dg,lfnmdonjfgdnolfdsfsgnonwedwdfwf wrfw wrfwfw wfwf wfwfwfw fwfwfwfw wwoblfnmdonjfgdnolfdsfsgnonwedwdfwf wrfw wrfwfw wfwf wfwfwfw fwfwfwfw wwob','TRB','L');


//----- Row 5 -----

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->SetXY(10,235);
$pdf->Cell(40,40,'English language','LRB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(50,235);
$pdf->Cell(25,40,'77','RB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(75,235);
$pdf->Cell(25,40,'87','RB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(100,235);
$pdf->Cell(25,40,'82','RB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(125,235);
$pdf->MultiCell(75,10,'dg,lfnmdonjfgdnolfdsfsgnonwedwdfwf wrfw wrfwfw wfwf wfwfwfw fwfwfwfw wwoblfnmdonjfgdnolfdsfsgnonwedwdfwf wrfw wrfwfw wfwf wfwfwfw fwfwfwfw wwob','TRB','L');


//----- Row 6 -----

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->SetXY(10,275);
$pdf->Cell(40,40,'English language','LRB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(50,275);
$pdf->Cell(25,40,'77','RB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(75,275);
$pdf->Cell(25,40,'87','RB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(100,275);
$pdf->Cell(25,40,'82','RB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(125,275);
$pdf->MultiCell(75,10,'dg,lfnmdonjfgdnolfdsfsgnonwedwdfwf wrfw wrfwfw wfwf wfwfwfw fwfwfwfw wwoblfnmdonjfgdnolfdsfsgnonwedwdfwf wrfw wrfwfw wfwf wfwfwfw fwfwfwfw wwob','TRB','L');



//-- Show Output --------
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After each 5 row add Table header in each page using a separate function and add only 5 row in each page. And repeat XY coordinate same as first page.

```
//----- Row 6 -----

//Next page Header(Better create a function for this)

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Cell(40,20,'Subject','LT',0,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(75,10,'First Term',1,1,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'','LRB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
$pdf->Cell(25,10,'October Test','TB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(25,10,'December Exam',1,0,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(25,10,'Term Average',1,0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(125,55);
$pdf->Cell(75,20,'Teacher\'s Evaluation','TRB',0,'C',0);

// Row 6 content

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->SetXY(10,75);
$pdf->Cell(40,40,'English language','LRB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(50,75);
$pdf->Cell(25,40,'77','RB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(75,75);
$pdf->Cell(25,40,'87','RB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(100,75);
$pdf->Cell(25,40,'82','RB',0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(125,75);
$pdf->MultiCell(75,10,'dg,lfnmdonjfgdnolfdsfsgnonwedwdfwf wrfw wrfwfw wfwf wfwfwfw fwfwfwfw wwoblfnmdonjfgdnolfdsfsgnonwedwdfwf wrfw wrfwfw wfwf wfwfwfw fwfwfwfw wwob','TRB','L');
```